# How can i fix this error "couldn't find the gcc toolchain"?

Tags: c++, gcc, android-ndk, cocos2d-x

I install cocos2d-x-v3.2 and android-ndk-r10 with command on windows and i get this error
    "couldn't find the gcc toolchain" because for android-ndk-r10 .now i want remove android-ndk-r10 and install android-ndk-r9 .
     i cant install (r9)

I remove this(C:\Users\Far...\android-ndk-r10) folder from location but it doesn't work

what should i do?

> ->Check environment variable NDK_ROOT
>             ->Search for environment variable NDK_ROOT...
>               ->NDK_ROOT is found : C:\Users\Far\android-ndk64-r10-windows-x86_64\android-
>           ndk-r10

Answer (score 0):

Once you've extracted the r9 Android NDK, you should set the `NDK_ROOT` environment variable to its location.

The procedure for setting/changing environment variables under Windows is described [here](https://superuser.com/a/284351/111708).